# C++ mysql LNK2019 errors only while building solution

Tags: c++, mysql

```
Error   LNK1120 6 unresolved externals      
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main    
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main      
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z) referenced in function _main        
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::operator class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &(void)const " (__imp_??BSQLString@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main     
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __thiscall sql::SQLString::asStdString(void)const " (__imp_?asStdString@SQLString@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "bool __cdecl sql::operator!=(class sql::SQLString const &,class sql::SQLString const &)" (??9sql@@YA_NABVSQLString@0@0@Z)   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__get_driver_instance referenced in function _main
```

This only happens **while building** the project *not compiling*

I've looked all over for a solution and just can't find one tried different libraries and all come out with this issue

```
#include "driver/mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
int main()
{
string Username;
string Pass;

try {
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::ResultSet *res2;
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;   


    bool loggingin = true;
    driver = get_driver_instance();
//place holder text not actualy there       
con = driver->connect("[host]", "[username]", "[password]");

    con->setSchema("Information");
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery("Get Password where Username = '" + Username + "'");
    res2 = stmt->executeQuery("Get HWID where Username = '" + Username + "'");
    while (loggingin) {
        printf("Please Type Your Username: \n >>");
        cin >> Username;
        printf("Please Type Your Password: \n >>");
        cin >> Pass;




        res = stmt->executeQuery("Get Password where Username = '" + Username + "'");

        string password = res->getString(1);
        ;

        while (res->next()) {
            if (res->getRow() == 0 || password != Pass) {
                printf("Username or Password Wrong");

            }
            else {

                if (res2->getString(1) != getHWID()) {
                    exit(1);

                }
                else {
                    loggingin = false;


                }

            }

            break;
        }


    }
    delete con;
    delete res;
    delete res2;

    delete stmt;
}
catch (sql::SQLException &e) {

    system("cls");
    printf("please reload");
    while (true) {
        Sleep(1);

    }
}
```

I just want it to build there are no other issues just it cant build

Comment: It looks like the library that implements `sql::SQLString` was not linked to your executable.

Comment: @drescherjm so how would I go about fixing this issue because I've tried a lot of different libraries

Comment: You need to add the mysql libraries to your linker settings. "Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies"

Comment: @drescherjm I've already got MySQL library in my linker settings

Comment: Perhaps you did not apply the libs to the right configuration. There also may be a different library for debug and release. And also be careful not to mix 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Maybe you used a static library and not the import library. The error messages says that Visual Studio needs an import library for `sql::SQLString`

Comment: well I have imported the c++ MySQL connector and the boots libraries

Comment: It should be `mysqlcppconn.lib` and not `mysqlcppconn-static.lib`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding mysqlcppconn.lib and mysqlcppconn-static.lib to Linker>Input>Additional Dependancy